Water seeping through shower enclosure in newly built home. Should tile be against drywall?
EDIT - Adding a couple more photos and context. There is cement board where the shower handle is that can be seen when the handle is removed but how far that goes is the question.
I got a cheap endoscope from amazon and unfortunately there is a 2x4 like 1 inch in from the hole that is blocking me from seeing past it. These are pictures of the outside corner of the shower where the non tile wall meets the drywall.
Link to pictures more pictures.
https://imgur.com/a/xT52h2I
We bought a newly built house from a big builder which is still under warranty and the shower enclosure has been seeping water into the drywall and baseboard which created a bit of mold that has been abated. The wall is still open and test strips are still saying moisture is present.
Tile guy put some caulk on it and said it's the shower enclosure, shower door guys took apart the door and everything was caulked to all hell but he said it shouldn't have caused it, plumber came and said it's not a plumbing leak and it's the tile. The idiot customer service rep I'm dealing with doesn't seem to understand the problem and I'm not a contractor so maybe I'm not explaining it well.
The tile at the edge seems to be put on drywall with waterproofing behind it. As I understand tile and grout aren't waterproof so water can be expected to seep through it into whatever is behind it. Shouldn't there be some sort of water proofing behind the tile in between the drywall? Looking at other similar posts that seems to be the case but I'm looking for some reassurance here that I'm not crazy and the customer service rep doesn't know jack shit.
Thanks for all your help! From what I can find on the internet there should be some sort of waterproofing between the tile and anything that can get wet. There is hot mop in there but behind the drywall and MDF baseboard.

I'm a bit confused.  Is there tile on drywall in the shower?  Or is this outside the shower wall, like next to it?  Tile should never be on drywall for a shower.

It's outside the shower door right next to the enclosure. It's like the last 2 inches just outside the actual door is on drywall. There is a stud in the way that is blocking me from seeing how far the drywall goes into the shower.
There is definitely cement board inside the tile that can be seen when accessing the shower valve and cartridge area. Sorry for the confusion, I'm not sure how to explain all of this!

You made it much clearer, Thank You.

@MikeKrak please update your post ... the comment you wrote is not considered as a part of the question

Looks to me like the drywall continues under the tile, which is a huge no-no in a shower.  Can you get a cheap endoscope to see behind that, like how far the drywall may extend (you may run into a stud)?  Of course, the limited context of the photos makes it difficult to see exactly what's going on—can you add some more?

There is definitely cement board behind the tile but where it starts and where the drywall begins is what I'm concerned with. When the shower handle is pulled off the cement board can be seen but I have no idea how far that actually goes.
